# Solvable PDEs and their Green's functions

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, linear-pde, fourier-transform, green-function

I have a class of PDEs of the form
$$
     -\Box\phi(x)+\lambda\phi_0^2(x)\phi(x)=0
$$
with $\phi_0^2(x)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty b_ne^{ip_n\cdot x}$. I know some exact solutions for them (see [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1310.6630) and [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/0907.4053)). Then, I consider their Green's functions, being these linear equations, and I want to solve
$$
     -\Box G(x)+\lambda\phi_0^2(x)G(x)=\delta^4(x).
$$
Using linearity, I can apply a Fourier transform and I get
$$
     p^2\tilde G(p)+\lambda\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty b_n\tilde G(p_n-p)=1.
$$
Is there any reasonable approach to get a solution out of this equation?

Comment: the only general approach (valid for any $\phi_0$) I can think of is a numerical solution; is that reasonable enough?

Comment: @CarloBeenakker: It could be having an analytical solution to compare with. Indeed, this seems the case.